# OSX Maps displays a non existant iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, maps

I have recently had my iPhone 5 replaced at the apple store due to an antenna failure. At the time it was running iOS 7 and upon handing it over to receive the new one, iCloud was disabled and the phone was then erased and restored.

Now when I updated to Mavericks, the maps app now displays the old iPhone and the new one.

[image: Maps screenshot]

How can I get rid of the inactive iPhone? The two constantly swap around and if I want to send directions to my phone I'm forced to send it to both of them twice since every time I open the dropdown, they keep swapping around. And I realize that it's becoming a huge pain.

Comment: What happens if you rename your current phone (on the iPhone itself)? If the name would get updated in Maps as well you at least would know which is which.

Comment: Yeah but I would prefer that the old one is completely gone. It's presence simply annoys me!

Comment: I've got a similar problem with my old 4S, which at least has a different name. I'd love to know what Maps bases its list on.

Comment: Yeah I would love to know as well. I looked through the Apple ID management on the apple website but there was no list of "assigned devices" that I could find.

Comment: Is the old device still shown in Find my iPhone?

Comment: @Undo No it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a fix for this!

The fault lies on the Mac itself. Simply signing out of iCloud on the Mac and signing back in removes any past iCloud enabled devices from Maps.

Although this caused [a new problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116421/icloud-cannot-enable-calendar-and-reminders-at-the-same-time), it fixed the annoying Maps problem. Other than that hope this helps others out there experiencing the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Rename your iPhone in iTunes or Settings > General > About > Name. Why you have both listed still might be because it is referencing the two individual device backups in iTunes (~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup)

Comment: How would I know which one it is?
http://dumpt.com/img/files/wvhu0eln6mv82s2c7k8k.png

Comment: Examine the date of creation for the folders either by using command + I or changing the Finder window layout to list instead of column.

Comment: Forgot to reply to this. I did what you said and attempted to remove the backup of the phone I no longer need and it still appears in the list.

Comment: With all updates to OS X and iOS?

Comment: Always up to date with the latest